# How to get more information from PDO failure "Error!: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"?

Tags: php, error-handling, pdo

Every once in a while I get an error such as the following with PDO:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Is there any way to get a more specific error, such as a line number, filename, the parameter that is missing, etc., instead of a vague message?

Comment: Set PDO to throw exceptions (`$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`). This will cause your app to die and dump a stack trace when it happens - I do this as a matter of course and wrap every PDO operation/set of operations in a try/catch with error handling as appropriate. But frankly if your error log is not logging file/line no already and you need to do this, it's not up to much.

Comment: @DaveRandom - I already have those settings set, and my queries are inside a try/catch block. I assume that's why I got the error I did.

Comment: Well in that case presumably you are doing something like `echo $e->getMessage()` in the `catch` block? Well change it to `echo $e->getMessage().' in '.$e->getFile().' on line '.$e->getLine();` instead and you'll get the information you want. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

Comment: @DaveRandom - Thanks, that is very helpful! Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, ensure that you have PDO set to throw exceptions on error:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Now, ensure that every PDO operation/set of operations is enclosed a `try`/`catch` block, something like this:

```
try {

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Whatever");
  // ...yada yada yada, your PDO code goes here

} catch (PDOException $e) {

  // This will echo the error message along with the file/line no on which the
  // exception was thrown. You could e.g. log the string to a file instead.
  echo $e->getMessage().' in '.$e->getFile().' on line '.$e->getLine();

}
```

All exceptions extend from the base [`Exception`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) class, and so inherit it's methods and the information it carries about errors.

As a side note, if using PDO with MySQL, ensure that you disable emulated prepared statements. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/889949) for more info on how to do this and why you should.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is register a global error handler and a global exception handler. Those functions receive filename, linenumber and error message. In those functions, echo the data to the screen and die.